# Using TypeScript in Node.js project with "module": "commonjs"

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

TypeScript documentation [says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#the-module-output-format):

> Node.js’s rules for module format detection and interoperability make it incorrect
> to specify `module` as `esnext` or `commonjs` for projects that run in Node.js, even if
> all files emitted by `tsc` are ESM or CJS, respectively.

I'm trying to get full list of what exactly is incorrect and what are potential consequences. I tried to build simple hello world with `"module": "commonjs"` in my `tsconfig.json` and, except for the fact it is transpiled to quite unreadable code output, code is perfectly runnable by Node 20.

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```

and then I have two files `index.ts` and `module.ts`:

`index.ts`:

```
import { car } from "./module"; console.log("car", car)
```

`module.ts`:

```
export const car = {
  brand: "Ford",
  model: "Fiesta",
};
```

I build it with `tsc --build` and I get properly built `index.js` and `module.js`, perfectly runnable by Node. This is obviously super simple but has module resolution and works. What has to be done to break things and see that having `"module": "commonjs"` is indeed incorrect as the documentation says?

Comment: What _is_ your hello world; does it have any module resolution?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes. I will edit orginal question